# Змейка на Java проблема с timer

Tags: java

Пишу змейку.

Проблема в том, что сама змейка из 3х блоков не начинает движение.

*timer delay* стоит 250 и по прошествии 250мс программа просто заканчивается.

Задумано так, что при запуске она просто поползёт вправо и далее можно будет ею управлять, но до этого не доходит.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;

public class SneakyField extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private final int Size = 320;
    private final int dotSize = 16;
    private final int allDots = 400;
    private Image dot;
    private Image apple;
    private int appleX;
    private int appleY;
    private int[] x = new int[allDots];
    private int[] y = new int[allDots];
    private int dots;
    private Timer timer;
    private boolean left = false;
    private boolean right = true;
    private boolean up = false;
    private boolean down = false;
    private boolean inGame = true;


    public SneakyField() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        loadImages();
        initGame();
        addKeyListener(new FieldKeyListener());
        setFocusable(true);

    }

    public void initGame() {
        dots = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < dots; i++) {
            x[i] = 48 - i * dotSize;
            y[i] = 48;
        }
        timer = new Timer(250, this);
        timer.start();
        createApple();

    }

    public void createApple() {
        appleX = new Random().nextInt(20) * dotSize;
        appleY = new Random().nextInt(20) * dotSize;

    }

    public void loadImages() {
        ImageIcon iia = new ImageIcon("src/dot.png");
        dot = iia.getImage();
        ImageIcon iia2 = new ImageIcon("src/apple.png");
        apple = iia2.getImage();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (inGame) {
                g.drawImage(apple, appleX, appleY, this);
                for (int i = 0; i < dots; i++) {
                    g.drawImage(dot, x[i], y[i], this);
                }
        }
        else {
            String str = "Game Over";
            //Font f = new Font("Arial",14,Font.BOLD);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            //g.setFont(f);
            g.drawString(str, 125, Size/2);
        }
    }


    public void move() {
        for (int i = dots; i > 0; i--) {
            x[i] = x[i - 1];
            y[i] = y[i - 1];
        }
        if (left) {
            x[0] -= dotSize;
        }
        if (right) {
            x[0] += dotSize;
        }
        if (up) {
            y[0] -= dotSize;
        }
        if (down) {
            y[0] += dotSize;
        }
    }

    public void checkApple() {
        if (x[0] == appleX && y[0] == appleY) {
            {
                dots++;
                if (dots % 5 == 0) {
                    timer.setDelay(timer.getDelay() - 50);
                }
                createApple();
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkCollisions() {
        for (int i = dots; i > 0; i--) {
            if (i > 4 && x[0] == x[i] && y[0] == y[i]) {
                inGame = false;
            }
        }
        if (x[0] > Size) {
            inGame = false;
        }
        if (x[0] > 0) {
            inGame = false;
        }
        if (y[0] > Size) {
            inGame = false;
        }
        if (x[0] > 0) {
            inGame = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (inGame) {
            move();
            checkApple();
            checkCollisions();
        }
        repaint();
    }

    class FieldKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            super.keyPressed(e);
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && !right) {
                left = true;
                up = false;
                down = false;
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && !left) {
                right = true;
                up = false;
                down = false;
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP && !down) {
                up = true;
                left = false;
                right = false;
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && !up) {
                down = true;
                left = false;
                right = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Разделяй и властвуй -- один из принципов программирования. 1) ты можешь создать окно, которое не будет закрываться (по срайней мере, само) и будет видно? 2) ты можешь добавить в это окно изображения? 3) ты можешь заставить двигаться эти изображения? 4) выполни дебаг программы или напиши тесты для змейки

Comment: По первым двум пунктам - вроде бы да, окно создаётся, само не закрывается, хотя быстро уходит в Game over, но рабочее поле остаётся на месте. Изображения так же присутствуют. Но вот заставить двигаться эти изображения у меня не получается. По сути, в этом то и проблема. Вроде бы за это отвечает timer, но я не уверен, да и где ошибка - увы не понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно проблема с управлением. Попробуй создать, и подключить класс game.java, пиши в нём это, и предыдущий код в первом файле:

```
private class MyKey implements KeyListener
{

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();// определяем код нажатой клавиши
        
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)myGame.new_napr = 0;
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)myGame.new_napr = 1;
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)myGame.new_napr = 2;
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)myGame.new_napr = 3;
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    
}
```

Код второго файла:

```
    if (napr == 0) // влево 
    {
        if(gX-1>=0)
            gX--;
        else
            gX = 29;
    }
    if (napr == 2) {
        if(gY-1>=0)
            gY--;
        else
            gY = 29;
    }
    else
        if (napr == 1)
        {
            if(gX+1<=29)
                gX++;
            else
                gX = 0;
        }
        else
            if (napr == 3)
            {
                if(gY+1<=29)
                    gY++;
                else
                    gY = 0;
            }
```

Comment: Если честно, сомневаюсь, что тут дело в таймере (может я и не прав, конечно, но ваш код не смог нормально подставить). Может это быть из-за того, что в обучающем видео была Java 8, а у меня 11?